# [FastAPI]Cannot delete s3 object with boto3 and all policy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

I am trying to connect S3 to my FastAPI project.

I've successfully uploaded images through IAM permissions and S3 bucket permissions settings,

but I'm repeatedly facing 'Access Denied' errors when trying to delete them.

> ```
> INFO:     127.0.0.1:56293 - "DELETE /api/feed/delete/5 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
> ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
>     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
>     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 292, in __call__
>     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
>     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
>     raise exc
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
>     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
>     raise exc
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
>     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
>     raise e
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
>     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
>     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
>     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
>     response = await func(request)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 273, in app
>     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 192, in run_endpoint_function
>     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
>     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
>     return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
>     return await future
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
>     result = context.run(func, *args)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/Users/gnimom/Documents/Personal/FastAPI_SQLAlchemy_Pydantic/FastAPI_SQLAlchemy_Pydantic/routers/feed_router.py", line 70, in delete
>     feed_service.delete_feed(db, feed_id, email)
>   File "/Users/gnimom/Documents/Personal/FastAPI_SQLAlchemy_Pydantic/FastAPI_SQLAlchemy_Pydantic/services/feed_service.py", line 161, in delete_feed
>     delete_image_from_s3(image_url)
>   File "/Users/gnimom/Documents/Personal/FastAPI_SQLAlchemy_Pydantic/FastAPI_SQLAlchemy_Pydantic/services/feed_service.py", line 190, in delete_image_from_s3
>     s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET, Key=image_name)
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 535, in _api_call
>     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 980, in _make_api_call
>     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
> ```

Here's my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-fastapi",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-fastapi/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and my IAM policy has S3FullAccess.

What would be the problem? here's my code too:

```
import boto3
from config import settings

s3_client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_SECRET_KEY,
    region_name="ap-northeast-2",
)
```

```
def delete_image_from_s3(image_url: str):
    image_name = image_url.split("/")[-1]
    bucket_name = settings.S3_BUCKET

    logging.debug(f"Deleting from Bucket: {bucket_name}, Key: {image_name}")

    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET, Key=image_name)
```

I have tried almost everything that I can find.

Additionally, I've double-checked multiple times that there are no typos in the bucket name and keys on my code.

There are no versioning activities and the file that has the key surely exists

How can I resolve this error?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Possible reasons include: you've used the wrong bucket name, an S3 bucket policy is preventing you deleting objects, your credentials are actually for a different AWS account, your credentials don't actually have s3:DeleteObject permissions on the relevant object(s), or an organization SCP is preventing you deleting objects.

Comment: I appreciate your response to my post. I've been double-checking the mentioned aspects multiple times, but I've successfully uploaded to the same bucket. Therefore, the likelihood of errors in the bucket name or access keys is very low. I've reviewed both the IAM and bucket policies as you mentioned, and everything appears to be in order.

Comment: As an FYI that's a very dangerous S3 bucket policy. You should delete/modify it asap to provide the minimal permissions (possibly none at all, but possibly s3:GetObject if you want to provide unauthenticated downloads). Your application should ideally get permission from an IAM role, not from IAM user credentials, and definitely not from the S3 bucket policy.

Comment: Thank you. Initially, I had allowed only minimal access, but I kept encountering the same error. So, I've temporarily opened up access to the maximum and I'm currently testing. Once I resolve the policy issue I'm currently facing, I plan to narrow it down to the appropriate policy. Thanks again for the helpful information.

Comment: Were the objects you are trying to delete uploaded from a different account? Is it only deletion you get errors on?

Comment: It was uploaded exactly same account. and YES only deletion is the problem. Thanks